# Detect wifi connection on a Pocket PC

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, wifi, pocketpc

I am trying to programmatically detect if a Pocket PC has a wifi connection or not.  Detecting any connection would probably work, as wifi will be the only possibility.

Once a connection is detected data will be downloaded from a web service.

I am developing in VB but anything in C# is fine.

On Windows Mobile there is the `SystemState` class from `Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Status` which would work, but this is not available on Pocket PC.  An equivalent would be excellent but I can't find one.

There may well be a manufactures API that could be used, but I would prefer not to be tied to a manufacturer.
I am also not allowed to use anything third party, which rules out getting an off the shelf solution.

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: What are you going to do once you've found out? If it's `<make some network request>`, you canjust try that anyway and see if it works

Comment: Once a connection is detected data will be downloaded from a web service

Comment: Guessed it might be that. Why not just try to download the data anyway? If it works, great; if not, you know you haven't got a network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send a UDP packet to somwhere where it will do no harm and check if it errors out

Comment: What would be the easiest way of sending out a UDP packet? Thanks

Comment: The Socket class has easy methods for that - please use MSDN search or leave another comment if you require help.

Answer (score 0):

In which version of PocketPC are you working?

Because I have used Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Status namespace on Windows Mobile Standard and Windows Mobile Professional (PPC).

Comment: It's version 4.20.0 (Build 14053). I had a test app using Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Status working on WM5 but failed on PPC